# Adding trailing 0 in log4j (zip) file name

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j to log data. I specify the zip file using an expression like
`<dir_name>/$${date:yyyy-MM}/<app_name>-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz`
This works mostly as desired, except that I get a file name like
`<app_name>-2022-01-20-1.log.gz`,
while I want a leading zero before the 1. I am fairly certain that the number of log files will be in 2 digits, and having a leading zero helps in getting things in order while grepping across multiple files, and improves other sysadmin/debugging for the same reason.

I tried using
`<dir_name>/$${date:yyyy-MM}/<app_name>-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%ii.log.gz`, but it didn't work, not that I really expected it to.

I couldn't find any documentation on what variant of %i (if any) results in a leading 0 in file name.

Any help or hints, or links to log4j documentation which covers this would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `%02i` work as you expect it to?

Comment: Great that it worked. I have created an answer based on that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the Log4J documentation for example here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html for the `filePattern` field.

The `DefaultRolloverStrategy` will accept both a date/time pattern compatible with `SimpleDateFormat` and/or a `%i` which represents an integer counter. The integer counter allows specifying a padding, like `%3i` for space-padding the counter to 3 digits or (usually more useful) `%03i` for zero-padding the counter to 3 digits.

So in order for you to zero-pad your file counter with two digits you would use `%02i`.

Comment: Huh. I had actually visited the page you linked to, but completely missed the bit about %03i. Thanks for answering this.